# Display images from list in girdview and save them in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my first question, I'm new developer, I'm trying to display images that are existing in a list and I want to save them in sqlite database, here is my code (I took the images from databse distant and I display them in this code in a list view but it doesn't look good for me):

```
public class GetImagesFromDropBox extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    InputStream is;
    ImageView img, img2,myconvertimage;
    Button btn, btn2;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmapOrg;
    String result = "";
     SQLiteDatabase db;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table tb if not exists tb (a blob )");
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy threadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicy);
        setContentView(R.layout.listeimages);
        Vector<Bitmap> ImageList = get_From_Cloud();
         SetTheList(ImageList);
    }
    private void SetTheList(Vector<Bitmap> cantactList) {

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewimages);
         ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter = new MY_ArrayAdapter(GetImagesFromDropBox.this,R.layout.rowimages, cantactList);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);


        /* list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View viewClicked, int position,long id) {


          saveImage(viewClicked);


                }

            private void saveImage(View view ) {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream();





            }});*/



          }
           public class MY_ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {
            Vector<Bitmap> liste_user;

            public MY_ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                    Vector<Bitmap> liste_user) {
                super(context, resource, liste_user);
                this.liste_user = liste_user;
            }



            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View ItemView = convertView;
                if (ItemView == null) {
                ItemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowimages,parent, false);
                                                        }
                Bitmap curentUser = liste_user.get(position);

               ImageView img=(ImageView)ItemView.findViewById(R.id.imagefromdropboxxx);
               img.setImageBitmap(curentUser);

             return ItemView;
             }
            }


    private Vector<Bitmap> get_From_Cloud() {
        String str1 = "";
        Vector<Bitmap> imageviewslist = new Vector<Bitmap>();

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", "charger"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nom", "img1200"));

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new

            HttpPost("http://thecloudtelecom.esy.es/uplodefilee.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            int j = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                j++;
                if (j >= 3) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // Parse les données JSON
        try {
            Vector<ImageBytes> imagebyte = new Vector<ImageBytes>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = json_data.getInt("id");
                String nom = json_data.getString("nom");
                str1 = json_data.getString("contenue");
                Log.e(" ID  of image ", "  " + id);
                imagebyte.add(new ImageBytes(nom, id, str1));

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < imagebyte.size(); i++) {
                byte[] ba2 = Base64.decode(imagebyte.get(i).getBa());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba2, 0, ba2.length);

                imageviewslist.add(bitmap);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageviewslist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to ask one specific question per post. This seems to be two questions.

Comment: ok , i'm trying to display images from list view to girdview